# Using blazor components to handle login in razor Login page?

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-pages, mudblazor

I’m building a Blazor Server application, and I’m setting up user authentication. I’ve built out the scaffolding in the way prescribed by microsoft, and I understand that authentication currently has to be done through a razor page- however, I also know that it’s possible to use blazor components in an MVC view.

My question is, would I be able to handle the login flow (Setting the default @Model’s attributes) using blazor components?

I’m using mudblazor for my UI and the whole application looks very cohesive- except the splash page which is obviously jarringly different.

Is this possible? Should I just style the razor page to look like MudBlazor as best I can?

Comment: Blazor is an SPA, which means that headers are already processed by the time the browser renders the page.  This is why we have this awkward MVC scaffolding instead of simple Blazor components.  You are correct-- style the Identity pages to look like the rest of your site.

Comment: You should read up on the plans for .net 8, before you spend too much effort.

Comment: @HH Appreicate the tip- found that [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-3/](.net 8 preview page), excited for a potentially less clunky solution in the future.